# Javascript: (implicitely) call a final method after method chains

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to call a method "implicitely" after a chain (fluent interface pattern).

I already have something like

```js
class Foobar {
  methodA() {
    // update state
    return this;
  }

  methodB() {
    // update state
    return this;
  }

  applyChanges() {
    // persist the state at this point
  }
}
```

And on the usage:

```
new Foobar().methodA().methodB().applyChanges();
```

The thing here, is that I don't know in advance if users of the class will use only one chain method or two (or even zero) and for "developer experience", I didn't want to expose the `applyChanges` method.

Is there a way to perform that? Or even another pattern I could implement. For example, I thought I could stack the method calls first, but I still won't know when to stop and execute the `applyChanges` method :(

Comment: What should happen if someone does the following:
`const foobar = new Foobar().methodA(); foobar.methodB();`
I think you cannot avoid passing the responsibility of calling `applyChanges` to the caller or else i guess you should call `applyChanges` in `methodA` and `methodB`.

Answer (score 0):

If the `applyChanges` operation were `async` (and I'm guessing the "persisting" might need something asynchronous anyway), it would be easy: you could have a `then` method like this:

```js
async applyChanges () { /*...*/ }

then (success, failure) {
  return this.applyChanges().then(success, failure)
}
```

Then `await`ing your object would implicitly apply changes and wait for them to be done (`await new Foobar().methodA().methodB()`), because `async`/`await` uses promises under the hood, so `await x` will cause `x.then` to be called if existing. This is how Mongoose query objects behave for example.

Comment: I think the "persisting" here was misleading. I actually don't have anything asynchronous unfortunately. I'm actually trying to create a small class for creating HTTP mocks and the API i had in mind was something like:

`mockRequest(url).withStatus(400).withPayload(somePayload).withHeaders(headersSet)
`

But I'm using Polly.js as underlying library for the HTTP mocks so I wanted to "register" the handler only after that line is written

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I actually got away with it thanks to Polly. Because it lazily evaluates the http handler i'm building, it gets the "right version" of it when the HTTP requests happen :)